# How to SELECT multiple values in different tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have here a 3 tables. User Table, Employee Table and Report Table.

User Table has 4 columns:

```
ID, Username, Password, Role
1    test       test    Admin
2    branch     branch  Manager
3    hello      hello   Manager
```

Employee Table has 4 columns:

```
ID, Firstname, Lastname, Supervisor_ID
1    test       test      
2    branch     branch   
3    hello      hello   
4    agent1     agent1      2
5    agent2     agent2      2
6    agent3     agent3      3
7    agent4     agent4      3
```

Report Table has 4 columns:

```
Report_ID, ID, Branch_ID, Client_ID
   1       1      1           1
   2       2      1           1
   3       3      2           3
   4       4      1           2
   5       5      3           4
   6       6      3           2
   7       7      2           5
```

Now the desired output that I want is that if the user who login is a manager then the reports that he can see is only the reports under his `ID` and the agents under his supervision. I have a code here that selects only two values from the tables.

```
      $user = $_SESSION['username'];

      $statement="SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username='".$user."'";
      $result1 = mysqlparser($statement, $db);

      $id = $result1[0]['Employee_ID'];

      $statement="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Supervisor_ID='".$id."'";
      $result2 = mysqlparser($statement, $db);

      $id1 = $result2[0]['Employee_ID'];


      $statement = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE DATE(`Report_Timestamp`) = CURDATE() AND Employee_ID='".$id."' OR Employee_ID='".$id1."'";
      $result = mysqlparser($statement, $db);
```

**For example:**
I logged in branch which has an ID of 2. Now I want to see the reports from my ID and the other employees under my supervision which are agent1 and agent2.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `JOIN`s http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM Report
WHERE Employee_ID IN (
   SELECT T1.Id from Employee T1
   WHERE T1.supervisor_id = **MyId**)
```

This will give you the reports of all the employees that have MyId as a supervisor.
If you want to add MyId reports as well, just add an OR clause in the query or in the subquery :

```
SELECT * FROM Report
WHERE Employee_ID IN (
   SELECT T1.Id from Employee T1
   WHERE T1.supervisor_id = **MyId**)
OR Employee_Id = **MyId**
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that you can still make another select statement in a select statement. Now I know. Another addition to my knowledge.